# ML kit in bubble.io

Tags: google-mlkit, bubble.io

I want to use ML kit barcode scanning functionality in bubble.io, but not able to understand how to use it on this platform or any other no code platform

if anyone has used it or have idea how it can be used in bubble.io

Comment: ML Kit supports only mobile platforms (Android & iOS).

Answer (score 0):

If you are integrating RestAPI then use the API connector plugin.
If it is SDK then create your custom plugin. In serverside actions, you can install npm packages of the SDK and write your code.

For further help reach out to me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).